# Show 4 Camera previews with surfaceview from 4 sources with different ids and capture images from each one

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have a code that show camera with `SurfaceView` and capture image from that camera.
Now i want to show 4 camera with `SurfaceView` together and capture image when touch each one of them. 
Camera ids are `2`, `3`, `4`, `5`.
I read and use these links:
[Capture screen of SurfaceView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31154605/capture-screen-of-surfaceview) 
[how to create and save a screenshot from a surfaceview?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25091703/how-to-create-and-save-a-screenshot-from-a-surfaceview)
This is my code:

```
package com.example.foosurface;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.hardware.Camera;
import android.hardware.Camera.PictureCallback;
import android.hardware.Camera.ShutterCallback;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.view.SurfaceView;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.Toast;
    
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {

    protected static final int CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE = 0;
    private SurfaceView SurView;
    private SurfaceHolder camHolder;
    private boolean previewRunning;
    public static Camera camera = null;
    private RelativeLayout CamView;

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        CamView = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.camview);//RELATIVELAYOUT OR
        //ANY LAYOUT OF YOUR XML

        SurView = (SurfaceView)findViewById(R.id.sview);//SURFACEVIEW FOR THE PREVIEW
        //OF THE CAMERA FEED
        camHolder = SurView.getHolder();                           //NEEDED FOR THE PREVIEW
        camHolder.addCallback(this);                               //NEEDED FOR THE PREVIEW
        camHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);//NEEDED FOR THE PREVIEW

        Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1); //THE BUTTON FOR TAKING PICTURE

        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {    //THE BUTTON CODE
            public void onClick(View v) {
                camera.takePicture(shutterCallback, rawCallback, jpegCallback);//TAKING THE PICTURE
                //THE mPicture IS CALLED
                //WHICH IS THE LAST METHOD(SEE BELOW)
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width,//NEEDED FOR THE PREVIEW
                               int height) {
        if(previewRunning) {
            camera.stopPreview();
        }
        Camera.Parameters camParams = camera.getParameters();
        Camera.Size size = camParams.getSupportedPreviewSizes().get(0);
        camParams.setPreviewSize(size.width, size.height);
        camera.setParameters(camParams);
        try {
            camera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);
            camera.startPreview();
            previewRunning=true;
        } catch(IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {                  //NEEDED FOR THE PREVIEW
        try {
            camera=Camera.open();
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Error",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            finish();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {             //NEEDED FOR THE PREVIEW
        camera.stopPreview();
        camera.release();
        camera=null;
    }


    ShutterCallback shutterCallback = new ShutterCallback() {
        public void onShutter() {
            Log.d("TAG", "onShutter'd");
        }
    };

    /** Handles data for raw picture */
    PictureCallback rawCallback = new PictureCallback() {
        public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
            Log.d("TAG", "onPictureTaken - raw");
        }
    };

    /** Handles data for jpeg picture */
    PictureCallback jpegCallback = new PictureCallback() {
        public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {

            File myExternalFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+
                    File.separator+"Ultimate Entity Detector");
            File tmpFile = new File(myExternalFile,"TempGhost.jpg");
            try {
                tmpFile.delete();
                tmpFile.createNewFile();
                FileOutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(tmpFile);
                output.write(data);
                output.flush();
                output.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    };
}
```

My xml code :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:id="@+id/camview">

    <SurfaceView
        android:id="@+id/sview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

My question:
How to show 4 camera preview together with `surfaceview` and capture image from them?

Comment: Why not use a LinearLayout that have width and height as much as a parent and has vertical orientation, inside it, put 2 more linear layouts which have width as parent and height as wrap_content, making their orientation horizontal and inside them each one of them you put the relative layout that you call camview

Comment: @DanBaruch its not my problem. its ok to use LinearLayout. but my problem is how to use callback for each camera and how to define camera.takePicture for each camera holder.

Comment: In your code, you find the view of the camera and set everything you need for it. If you have 4 different views, each with a unique ID, and use the same code for each? Won't that work?

Comment: @DanBaruch i set everything for 4 different in my code, but i want to show and control 4 camera together and release every one i want and active every one when i want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my answer,
i used `holder.addCallback` for each holder.
it's one holder callback:

```
sHolder[0].addCallback(new SurfaceHolder.Callback() {
            @Override
            public void surfaceCreated(@NonNull SurfaceHolder holder) {
                try {
                    mCamera[0] =Camera.open(2);
                } catch(Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Error",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    getActivity().finish();
                }
                openAndStartCamera(0);
            }

            @Override
            public void surfaceChanged(@NonNull SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {
                if(previewRunning[0]) {
                    mCamera[0].stopPreview();
                }
                Camera.Parameters camParams0 = mCamera[0].getParameters();
                Camera.Size size0 = camParams0.getSupportedPreviewSizes().get(0);
                camParams0.setPreviewSize(size0.width, size0.height);
                mCamera[0].setParameters(camParams0);
                try {
                    mCamera[0].setPreviewDisplay(sHolder[0]);
                    mCamera[0].startPreview();
                    previewRunning[0]=true;
                } catch(IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void surfaceDestroyed(@NonNull SurfaceHolder holder) {
                mCamera[0].stopPreview();
                mCamera[0].release();
                mCamera[0]=null;
                previewRunning[0]=false;
                Log.e(TAG,"release camera");
            }
        });
```